# listview item text changes on scroll

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I have a list view in which i am binding multiple data like labels and image and i have that list in my frame so when list size gets greater then 10 items or so then on scroll my image resizes it self and text of label starts hide unhide.

Here is my xaml:

```
            <ListView 
                               x:Name="list" 
                               SelectionMode="None" 

                               SeparatorVisibility="None"
                               HasUnevenRows="True"
                               IsVisible="False"
                               BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                               ItemTapped="List_ItemTapped"
                               CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
                              >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                            <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10">

                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition 
        Height="Auto" />
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" 
        />
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition 
        Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition 
        Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Label 
                                                        Grid.Row="0" 
                                                        Grid.Column="0"

                                                        Text="{Binding Note}" 
                                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"  
                                                        TextColor="Black"  
        FontSize="Small"
                                                        FontFamily=" 
       {StaticResource BoldFont}"
                                                        FontAttributes="Bold">
                                                    </Label>
                                                    <ImageButton
                                                         Grid.Row="0"  
                                                         Grid.Column="1"


        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                        WidthRequest="22"
                                                        HeightRequest="22"
                                                        Padding="6"
                                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                        Clicked="btndelete"

        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"

        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                        Source="close.png">
                                                    </ImageButton>
                                                    <Label 
                                                            Grid.Row="1"  
                                                            Grid.Column="0"

                                                            Text="{Binding 
        NOfQuestions}"
                                                            FontSize="12"
                                                            FontFamily=" 
       {StaticResource Regular}"
                                                            TextColor="White">

                                                    </Label>
                                                    <Label 
                                                            Grid.Row="1"  
                                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                                            Margin="15,0,0,0"

                                                            Text="{Binding 
        NOfDigits}"
                                                            FontSize="12"
                                                            FontFamily=" 
       {StaticResource Regular}"
                                                            TextColor="White">

                                                    </Label>
                                                </Grid>

                                            </Frame>
        </ViewCell>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                          </ListView>
```

Here is the video of my problem in this video you can see that the list looks good but when i start to scroll it the text starts to hide unhide its size changes the cross image is getting small or big and on deleting the list item all the text disappears

[Gif video of my problem please watch this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLSyU.gif)

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I have having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior of re-rendering the list cells is generally related to the `ListView` Caching Strategy. It defines how the cells are cached and tries to improve the performance when loading lots of data, but can also screw with the proper display. Try messing up with the `CachingStrategy`. In past experience, setting it to "RecycleElement" solved render problems.

Also, check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance) for more information about ListView performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
                 <ListView 
                       x:Name="list" 
                       SelectionMode="None" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       SeparatorVisibility="None"
                       HasUnevenRows="True"                     
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
                      >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10">

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition 
                                 Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" 
                                        />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >


                                <Label                                                         
                                                Text="{Binding Note}" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  
                                                TextColor="Black"  
                                                FontSize="Small"
                                                FontFamily=" 
                                                {StaticResource BoldFont}"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold">
                                </Label>
                            <ImageButton
                                          
                                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                 WidthRequest="22"
                                                 HeightRequest="22"
                                                 Padding="6"
                                                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                 Clicked="btndelete"  
                                                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"    
                                                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                                Source="close.png">
                            </ImageButton>




                            </StackLayout>
                            
 

                            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label 
                                                    
                                                    Text="{Binding 
                                                    NOfQuestions}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                                    FontSize="12"
                                                    FontFamily=" 
                                                    {StaticResource Regular}"
                                                    TextColor="White">

                                </Label>
                                <Label 
                                                  
                                                    Margin="15,0,0,0"    
                                                    Text="{Binding 
                                                    NOfDigits}"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                    FontSize="12"
                                                    FontFamily=" 
                                                   {StaticResource Regular}"
                                                    TextColor="White">

                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                
                        </Grid>

                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Can you change the rowdefentions to some fixed values?

Comment: if we create a simple list with one label the same issue happened again with simple list as well

Comment: Are you adding scrollview before listview?

Comment: Can you change the rowdefentions to some fixed values?

Comment: still the same problem i changed the row defination height to 30

Comment: my xamarin forms is updated bro i am getting the same issue even if i create a simple list

Answer (score 0):

When you have custom cells in a `ListView` is recommended to use `CachingStrategy`

`ListView` is a powerful view for displaying data, but it has some limitations. Scrolling performance can suffer when using custom cells, especially when they contain deeply nested view hierarchies or use certain layouts that require complex measurement.

XAML for Xamarin.Forms provides a XAML attribute for a non-existent property that corresponds to the caching strategy argument :

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```